# How to set up single sign on for sharepoint integration in CRM 2011?

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, dynamics-crm

We have a working CRM 2011 and a Sharepoint 2010 environment. The problem is that everytime a CRM user tries to view the 'documents' page for a certain Account (as example here). A popup is shown to ask the CRM user to login to sharepoint.

I've heard it should be posible to setup a single sign on so the credentials are passed from crm to sharepoint. But i can't find documentation for this.

Anyone here who knows how to set this up?

Comment: We have just set up ADFS for Office 365 and CRM internally using IFD for CRM and can confirm that the claims token received from one app is not usable in another app. I.e. had to sign in twice agianst the same ADFS proxy. once for CRM and once for Office365. Have not tested this with an internal SharePoint setup though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible options

- If you don't have enabled IFD (and therefore claims based authentication), the simplest solution would be to configure IE, to pass the credentials of the current windows user to the site. Therefore you have to adjust the security configuration of the zone assigned to the SharePoint URL, to send the credentials of the current windows user. See following screen shot:
  [image]
- If you have enabled claims based authentication, the simplest solution would (IMHO) be to attach SharePoint to the same Token Service to which Dynamics CRM is attached. In this case it would be an instance of ADFSv2. See following links, which describe how to attach SharePoint to ADFSv2: [Configuring SharePoint 2010 and ADFS v2 End to End](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx) or [SharePoint 2010 and ADFS 2.0 the complete Step-by-Step guide](http://marcvaneijk.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-2-0-the-complete-step-by-step-guide/)

Comment: I just read your answer again and i noticed that this will pass my windows user to sharepoint. But i want to pass my CRM user credentials to sharepoint. I don't think this i going to work? Shall i need claims based authentication?

Comment: Independent of the decision whether you use claims or not you will always pass the windows user. Your crm user is tied to a specific windows user. If you _really_ need the crm user, please describe your requirement in detail, as it is an uncommon approach/requirement.

Comment: I tried the claims based method described in your first link. Everything went very well. Except that the article sais to use port 433 for my sharepoint webapplication. The problem is that this port is used for Version Control. Can't i use another port for this?

Comment: @ThomasDekiere to which article do you refer? You have to work with multiple bindings or multiple IP addresses (depends on your environment)

Answer (score 1):

Thomas, you can use port 443 to this effect.

Comment: please elaborate a bit to add more value on your answer

Answer (score 0):

Single sign:

[Office 365: Prepare for single sign-on](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/ff652540.aspx)

[Office 365: Single sign-on: Roadmap](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-enterprises/hh125004.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

you can config it by GPO in active directory. ( for full article click this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274846) )

But you can also config it in all of your clients from server.

Step 1: Open the Group Policy Editor by using Microsoft Management Console (MMC).

Step 2: Locate and click Internet Explorer Maintenance under Windows Settings in User Configuration.

Step 3: **click on that OPTION THAT YOU WANT** and change options

[image: auto config internet explorer with GPO]

like this, but remotely apply on all user you want.

[image: Internet explorer option - setting]